# How to get check if a certain user has {Write, read} permissions on a root node

Tags: java, magnolia

I want to write a method which has to return all the root nodes a certain user is able to write/read.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
public List<String> getAllowedRootPaths(String username) throws RepositoryException {

    SecuritySupport securitySupport = Components.getComponent(SecuritySupport.class);
    UserManager userManager = securitySupport.getUserManager();
    myUser = userManager.getUser(username);
    Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession("website");
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (getRoles().contains("rootPublisher")) {
                //check user access and add to array
        }
        return results;
    }

    public Collection<String> getRoles() {
       return magnoliaUser.getAllRoles();
    }
```

My old method was to use the

```
HierarchyManager hm = MgnlContext.getHierarchyManager("website");
```

and test

```
hm.isGranted(node.getPath(), Permission.READ)
```

but since thats deprecated I'm currently looking for another solution. I am aware that Session has a test for AccessRights but i seems that only works for a usersession.

Maybe someone has an Idea how to do that without manually grabbing the Roles and checking for the int values.

Greetings,
Hellfiend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccessManager#isGranted(node.getPath(), Permission.READ)`

Seems like the one you are looking for.

Hope that helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As Ducaz035 suggested you can do `MgnlContext.getAccessManager("website")` and call `isGranted()` on AccessManager.
Alternatively you can just call `PermissionUtil.isGranted(node,permission)` and let that method to locate proper access manager itself.